# Put all JSON value into individual <div>

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm quite new to JSON. What im trying to do is i have JSON with 3 objects in it and i want to put each objects into its respective  (there's 3 div). The code below doesn.t append anything to the

HTML:

```
    var testwrapper= $("<div/>").addClass("testwrapper").appendTo(somethingwrapper);
    var test1wrapper= $("<div/>").addClass("test One").appendTo(testwrapper);
    var test2rapper= $("<div/>").addClass("test Two").appendTo(testwrapper);
    var test3wrapper= $("<div/>").addClass("test Three").appendTo(testwrapper);

    <div class="Test One"></div>
    <div class="Test Two"></div>
    <div class="Test Three"></div>
```

JSON:

```
function dummytestJSON(){
         testJSON = {
            "Test" : 
            [
                {
                    "img" : "../img/test1.png",
                    "title" : "Test1",
                    "description" : "you have notification",
                    "time" : "2 mins ago"
                },
                {
                    "img" : "../img/test2.png",
                    "title" : "Test2",
                    "description" : "you have alerts",
                    "time" : "4 mins ago"
                },
                {
                    "img" : "../img/test3.png",
                    "title" : "Test3",
                    "description" : "you have notifications",
                    "time" : "9 mins ago"
                }
            ]
        };  
        //console.log(testJSON .Test_);
        return JSON.stringify(testJSON );
    }
```

Script:

```
function updateTest(){
    console.log("updating test");
    //console.log(testJSON);
    dummytestJSON();
    var testwrapper = ["Test One","Test Two","Test Three"];
    for(var test in testJSON.Test_){
        console.log(testJSON.Test_[test].title);

        var text = $("<p/>").text(testJSON.Test_[test ].title).appendTo("#"+testwrapper [test ]);

    }

}
```

Comment: This can be done in four steps: 1) convert json string to json object (`JSON.parse(...)`). 2) create a function that "translates" the first JSON object into a HTML node (div with image in it). 3) Add it to your HTML document (hint: `<node>.appendChild()`). 4)  When that's successful, use a loop and for each object, call that function (step 2) and add it to document (step 3). Done.

Answer (score 1):

i see this corrections:

The method dummytestJSON(), needs to return clean JSON , return testJSON;

And in method updateTest:

```
function updateTest(){
    console.log("updating test");
    //console.log(testJSON);
    var Test_ = dummytestJSON();
    var testwrapper = ["Test One","Test Two","Test Three"];
    for(var test in Test_){
        console.log(Test_[test].title);

        var text = $("<p/>").text(Test_[test ].title).appendTo("#"+testwrapper [test ]);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<div class="Test One" id="div_1"></div>
<div class="Test Two" id="div_2"></div>
<div class="Test Three" id="div_3"></div>
```

Then use

```
document.getElementById('div_1').innerHTML = ...
```

to set the contents.